# Why DatetimeComponents are no returning hours, minutes and seconds when converting GMT time

Tags: ios, datetime, nsdatecomponents, gmt

I'm converting date time(***2021-10-15 18:30:00 UTC,2021-10-15 18:30:00 +0000***) to datetime component but it's missing hours, minutes and seconds

```
let changedDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -10, to: actualDate)!
var datcomp = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day,.hour,.minute,.second], from: changedDate)
datcomp.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")
```

> ▿ 2021-10-15 18:30:00 +0000
>
> - timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate : 656015400.0
>
> ▿ timeZone: GMT (fixed) year: 2021 month: 10 day: 11 hour: 0 minute: 0
> second: 0 isLeapMonth: false    ▿ timeZone : GMT (fixed)
> - identifier : "GMT"
> - kind : "fixed"
> ▿ abbreviation : Optional
> - some : "GMT"
> - secondsFromGMT : 0
> - isDaylightSavingTime : false
>
> - year : 2021
> - month : 10
> - day : 11
> - hour : 0
> - minute : 0
> - second : 0
> - isLeapMonth : false

Some more logs

ActualDate:2021-09-26 18:30:00 +0000
changedDate:2021-09-21 18:30:00 +0000
Datecomp:year: 2021 month: 9 day: 22 hour: 0 minute: 0 second: 0 isLeapMonth: false

Comment: What is `actualDate`?  How was it created/set?

Comment: Its coming from API

Comment: When I see the value of variable , it appears as 2021-10-15 18:30:00 UTC

Comment: When I do print object , it appears as 2021-10-15 18:30:00 +0000

Comment: Can you please describe what it is that you are trying to do in this program? Are you trying to display a date somewhere? I feel like what you are doing in this question with the dateComponents is possibly not the best way of doing what you actually need to do. Thanks

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show the input string, the code that parses the input string and the result of printing `datcomp`?  I can't reproduce the results you are seeing

Comment: I am scheduling the local notification with datcomp.

Comment: You don’t need date components to do that. You just need a Date. When do you want the notification to fire? I’m guessing 10 days before the date provided by the api?

Comment: @Fogmeister - Yes 10 days before

Comment: I have some code snippets shared in this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/69310525/15140177 I have asked some other questions related with notification..if you could go to my profile , you may find it.I really appreciate your help

Comment: I'd suggest not using DateComponents to print a date. Just do `Print(date)`.

Comment: Can you show the output of `print(actualDate)` and `print(changedDate)` please?

Comment: `changedDate:2021-09-21 18:30:00 +0000` this looks right to me. Why can you not use this Date?

Answer (score 1):

Your API sends datetime in UTC.
You are subtracting days that's good as well.
But the problem is you are using date time components.

Datetime component will give date time object based on your current device settings.

As you are in India. Timezone difference is 5:30 and your datetime object has 6:30 PM hence it's 00:00:00

You consume other data which has time not 6:30 then you will start seeing hours,minutes and seconds

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I was going to answer with something similar. I didn't realise the OP was in India with a 5:30 time difference. Good catch. I would add that the `changedDat` in the OP is actually the correct Date that they should use.

Comment: Yes you are right. Date is local timezone agnostic  whereas DatetimeComponent is based on local device's calendar,timezone and locale

Comment: Thanks all this confusion solved. , I've wasn't aware of datetimecompents changing the date with respect to current timezone.  The whole confusion came from my local calendar notification trigger not firing for local notification. If you guys could have a look at this(https://stackoverflow.com/q/69310525/15140177) and find why notification is not firing, I'd appreciate that.